# how to send command to CMD to delete file from searched directory

Tags: c#

Hoping someone can help please?
I can open the Command Prompt from my code but can't work out how to get the files that were search for to delete them via command line.  So basically I can search a directory and file extensions which then displays in the listbox.  Then i have a button to delete these file (or selected files). I need to help on sending a command to delete the file it has found, eg: del "c:\filepath location\filename.xxx"  Hope i am making sense

here is my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        FolderBrowserDialog folderBrowserDlg = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        folderBrowserDlg.ShowNewFolderButton = true;
        DialogResult dlgResult = folderBrowserDlg.ShowDialog();
        if (dlgResult.Equals(DialogResult.OK))
        {
            textBox1.Text = folderBrowserDlg.SelectedPath;
            Environment.SpecialFolder rootFolder = folderBrowserDlg.RootFolder;
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Directory.Exists(textBox1.Text))
        {
            ext = textBox2.Text;
            count = 0;
            searchDirectory(textBox1.Text);
            MessageBox.Show("Total Files: " + count);
        }
    }
    int count = 0;
    string ext = "*.*";
    private string exeToRun;

    private void searchDirectory(string path)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(path))
            {
                if (file.EndsWith(ext))
                {
                    count++;
                    listBox1.Items.Add(file);
                }
            }
            foreach (string directory in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
            {
                searchDirectory(directory);

            }
        }

        catch (Exception) { }
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (listBox1.SelectedIndex != 1)
        {
            while (listBox1.SelectedIndex != -1)
            {
                string filepath = listBox1.Items[listBox1.SelectedIndex].ToString();
                if (File.Exists(filepath))
                    File.Delete(filepath);
                listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(listBox1.SelectedIndex);

            }
        }
    }

    private void button5_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\";
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.Start();


    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The .Net Framework has ways to deal with deleting files, so there is no need to start any external process.

Comment: what speaks against `FileInfo.Delete()` ?

Comment: And as a side note: you might consider giving your buttons "nice" names before you add handlers (so that the handlers then are clear what button / action is being done).

Comment: @crashmstr ... oh come on ... next thing you ask for is code comments and speaking variable names, eh? ... wasn't it hard to write and should be hard to read? ...scnr

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42 Am trying something to delete the files from CMD instead of normal way of deleting them (which works).  but am trying to delete them via CMD

Comment: well... in that case grab the new cmd.exe processes io streams and write your commands to them... ... even though that approach makes no sense

Comment: "I am trying" is not a *good reason* to do something very contrary to the normal way to do it. To do this, you need to understand how to tell `cmd.exe` what to do, which you are not doing at all.

Comment: @crashmstr that is why i am asking here for help. :-(

Comment: Open a command prompt and type `cmd /?` and read what it says, then try and build a command line that does what you need. Then you just need to build a string in your program that does that but with the file name from your other code. In other words: if you want to use the command line, understand how to use the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Change your command string from

```
CMD.EXE
```

to

```
CMD.EXE /C "DEL C:\MyFile.TXT"
```

The /C will execute the command string supplied and then terminate the command shell.